# Proxy ssh connection server-side

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, git, port-redirection

I have a server that was previously used for some git services. These have been moved to another server and I would like to, at least temporarily, ensure the user's repository remotes do not need to be altered by forwarding the ssh sessions.

The approach I had in mind is to share the `authorized_keys` file, which is managed by the git server, among both the old server and new git server, and authenticate against that. Since this file contains a `command="/some/script.sh"` to be executed on the git server I'd like to see if I can create some kind of proxy script in the same location on the old server.

There's a ton of info regarding jump servers, `ProxyCommand` etc. but all of these configure the 'hop' on client side. Is it possible to achieve this affect transparently, i.e. without having to alter anything on the clients? What would my /some/script.sh look like?